# What does "it makes too much sense" mean?

Tags: idioms, sarcasm

There's two possible and opposite ways to complete the popular expression ["it makes too much sense"](https://www.google.com/search?q=it%20makes%20too%20much%20sense) and thus give meaning to it:

- It makes too much sense *to be true, it must be false*
- It makes too much sense *to be false, it must be true*

Which one is it?

Comment: Related: [Irony](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony).

Comment: @Jolenealaska I can _guess_ it's ironic, but I can't be _certain._

Comment: It's actually not a common phrase, at least not in the US. Exactly what it means is going to vary with context, but it will always be ironic in tone.

Comment: To expand on the irony mentioned by @Jolenealaska: "Why didn't they enact that law?" "Because it makes too much sense!"

Comment: @TecBrat Exactly

Answer (score 2):

I usually think of this as meaning "It must be false", in an extremely sarcastic way. For example, if a political policy that seems sensible gets enacted into law, someone with a low opinion of their officials might say "There's no way our government made that policy. It makes too much sense."

Some people might say "It makes too much sense, it must be true", but I don't really think of that as an idiom; it means just what it says.

Answer (score 1):

It's irony or sarcasm. It takes the idea that the world/public/etc doesn't do things that are logical/right/good.

So, a logical decision based on facts is met with this sarcastic phrase.

"That makes too much sense..."

Answer (score 0):

Whenever 'too' is used in the sense of 'too much', it normally means 'too good to be true'.

So, when you say, 'this makes too much sense', I assume you mean, 'it must be false'.

Answer (score 0):

*too much* means more than required. You don't need that much of the thing.

> *[too much](http://www.audioenglish.org/dictionary/too_much.htm)* - more than necessary.

So,

> Do you call this whole-milk tea? It's **too much** of water in this, (and) there must be little milk.

Now, it makes it clearer.

> *It makes **too much** sense to be **true**, it must be false* - It gives sense that this as the truth is more than necessary, I smell a rat here...I doubt, it's false.

And vice versa...

Answer (score -1):

I actually have another variation on this — when it is followed by the phrase: NOT to  (do it, say it, enact, etc.) For example:

> "It made too much sense NOT to do."

So this follows an initial leaning or presumption NOT to do something, and it expresses that the decision has been reconsidered in light of the fact that it makes "too much sense NOT TO DO".

You might see it in this context:

> "We initially hated Bob's idea because he was such a jerk in the way he presented it, but after further consideration, we had to admit that **it made too much sense not to do**."